# Where to deploy the EJB-client.jar and the EJB-impl in Wildfly in a clean way?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, wildfly-10

i'm new in Java EE and i have implemented a simple EJB-Module with a remote Interface, which i want to deploy on Wildfly 10. In the `pom.xml` of the EJB-Module i have registered [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html) to generate the:

1. `ProcessApplicationEJBs-1.0-client.jar`
2. `ProcessApplicationEJBs-1.0.jar`

On the Wildfly-Server there are other deployed applications, which should use this ejb. For me it is important, that this applications use the client classes (hide the complete implementation). My questions are:

1. Where do i have to deploy the `ProcessApplicationEJBs-1.0-client.jar`? My plan was to register it as a new module in Wildfly. Is that right?
2. Where do i have to deploy the implementation `ProcessApplicationEJBs-1.0.jar`. As a module as well or in the normal deployments folder? I don't want that other deployed applications can see the concrete implementation, but the server will need the concrete implementations to provide the EJB's service. Do i have a missunderstanding here? What would be a common way to bring this to work in a clean way?

I would be be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to create a new module for WildFly and add a dependency in your application.
Or add a maven dependency to your project for the client to include the *-client.jar in the other application to be deployed together.

Benefit of a module is the class loading, if you use Local invocations (call by reference) the second option can fail if you share classes from the -client.jar because of the different classloaders.
Benefit of adding it to deployment is that you can change the interface without restarting the server or create a new module.